# $\sum(F\circ F)\geq x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, hadamard-product

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrix, denote by $A\circ B=(a_{ij}b_{ij})$.

> Let $C$ be an invertible real matrix. $D=diag(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, $F=CDC^{-1}$. Show that
> $\sum(F\circ F)\geq x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$, where $\sum$ means the sum of all entries of $F\circ F$.

If $C$ is the identity matrix, it is OK. What about other matrices?

Comment: Is $F \circ F$ just matrix product? If so, use the cyclic property of the trace $$\mathrm{tr}(F^2) = \mathrm{tr}(CDC^{-1} CDC^{-1}) = \mathrm{tr}(CD^2C^{-1}) = \mathrm{tr}(D^2C^{-1}C) = \mathrm{tr}(D^2) = \sum x_i^2.$$

Comment: @WillM. It seems to be element-wise multiplication, not matrix product.

Comment: @WillM. The operation $\circ$ is defined in the question.

Comment: Oh, yes, I clearly only read the title. I suppose it will have to do with the cycle property but it is not so straightforward then.

Comment: @WillM. Since the function of interest has shifted to $\operatorname{tr}(F^TF):\;$ if $C$ is orthogonal, then $F$ is symmetric, which takes us back to the equality in your original comment.

Comment: @greg OP (original poster) also asked it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222739/a-lower-bound-for-the-frobenius-norm

Answer (score 3):

$
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Here is a small $(n=3)\,$ counter-example
$$\eqalign{
&C = \m{
-1 & 6 & -6 \\
4 & 3 & 1 \\
-3 & 2 & 4 \\} \quad
x = \m{1\\2\\6} \\
&F = C\cdot\Diag{X}\cdot C^{-1}
 = \frac 1{113}\m{
425 & -174 & -336 \\
-14 & 186 & 102 \\
-151 & 182 & 406 \\}
\\\\
&\trace{F\circ F} = \frac{425^2+186^2+406^2}{113^2} \approx 29.76404 \\
&\|x\|^2 = 41 \\
}$$

Comment: Why your previous solutions wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately OP silently changed the trace to a sum over all matrix entries.